# monthly report to calculate start time and end time in SQL excluding Sunday

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have tables `[Mst_Daily_Report_Pds]` where I have start time and end time it calculates the date between  '11-01-2016'  and  '11-30-2016' and the output will be displayed into graph.

Ex:

```
8.5hrs * 7days = 59.5hrs,
8.5hrs * 6days = 51hrs
```

so the percentage is 85% which is wrong data.

My problem is it includes Sunday also which is not necessary how to exclude Sunday values?

Kindly check the below code:

```
select Name,Actual_Hours,round((Actual_Hours/((DATEDIFF(DAY,'11-01-2016'  ,'11-30-2016')+1)*8.5))*100,0) as percentage 
from (select Name , SUM(actual_Hours) Actual_Hours  
from ( select Name,ACTUAL_HOURS=sum(DATEPART(hh,[Time_Taken_in_Min]))+sum(DATEPART(MINUTE,[Time_Taken_in_Min])) /60  
FROM [HR_Admin].[dbo].[Mst_Daily_Report_Pds]  where date between  '11-01-2016'  and  '11-30-2016'   
    GROUP BY  Name )o group by Name  )a order by Actual_Hours desc
```

Kindly help me to exclude the Sunday values in over all percentage.

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected result ?

Comment: You should probably also need to exclude public holidays and cater for the days with reduced working hours (Saturdays??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create #tempTable to store the date between  '11-01-2016'  and  '11-30-2016' exclude Sunday by use @@DATEFIRST. @@DATEFIRST is used to set the first day of the week to a number from 1 through 7. So the temp table will be :

```
SELECT *  
FROM tempTable
WHERE ((DATEPART(dw, Date) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (1)
```

If your SQL database set Sunday is the first day of week.